# Facebook Account Kit for Web ( We're sorry, something went wrong ) Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

I have created an Account Kit sample for Web as per given in Facebook Account kit Documentation [[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/web)].

I am getting an error after submitting phone number and clicking on Login via SMS. Error Popup :

> (We're sorry, something went wrong).

Login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        Enter country code (e.g. +1):
    <input type="text" id="country_code" />
    Enter phone number without spaces (e.g. 444555666):
    <input type="text" id="phone_num"/>
    <button onclick="phone_btn_onclick();">Login via SMS</button>
    Enter email address
    <input type="text" id="email"/>
    <button onclick="email_btn_onclick();">Login via Email</button>
    <script>
  // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        appId:"288886378122244",
        state:"cswwsrf",
        version:"v1.0"
      }
    );
  };

  // login callback
  function loginCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
      document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
      document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
      document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
    else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
      // handle authentication failure
    }
    else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
      // handle bad parameters
    }
  }

  // phone form submission handler
  function phone_btn_onclick() {
    var country_code = document.getElementById("country_code").value;
    var ph_num = document.getElementById("phone_num").value;
    AccountKit.login('PHONE',
      {countryCode: country_code, phoneNumber: ph_num}, // will use default values if this is not specified
      loginCallback);
  }


  // email form submission handler
  function email_btn_onclick() {
    var email_address = document.getElementById("email").value;

    AccountKit.login('EMAIL', {emailAddress: email_address}, loginCallback);
  }

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Server.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Guid = require('guid');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Mustache  = require('mustache');
const Request  = require('request');
const Querystring  = require('querystring');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var csrf_guid = Guid.raw();
const api_version = 'v1.0';
const app_id = '288886378122244';
const app_secret = 'f67b17e61d3ac36350b5f325be77659f';
const me_endpoint_base_url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/me';
const token_exchange_base_url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token';


function loadLogin() {
  return fs.readFileSync('login.php').toString();
}

app.get('/', function(request, response){
  var view = {
    appId: app_id,
    csrf: csrf_guid,
    version: account_kit_api_version,
  };

  var html = Mustache.to_html(loadLogin(), view);
  response.send(html);
});

function loadLoginSuccess() {
  return fs.readFileSync('login_success.html').toString();
}

app.post('/sendcode', function(request, response){
  console.log('code: ' + request.body.code);

  // CSRF check
  if (request.body.csrf_nonce === csrf_guid) {
    var app_access_token = ['AA', app_id, app_secret].join('|');
    var params = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: request.body.code,
      access_token: app_access_token
    };

    // exchange tokens
    var token_exchange_url = token_exchange_base_url + '?' + Querystring.stringify(params);
    Request.get({url: token_exchange_url, json: true}, function(err, resp, respBody) {
      var view = {
        user_access_token: respBody.access_token,
        expires_at: respBody.expires_at,
        user_id: respBody.id,
      };

      // get account details at /me endpoint
      var me_endpoint_url = me_endpoint_base_url + '?access_token=' + respBody.access_token;
      Request.get({url: me_endpoint_url, json:true }, function(err, resp, respBody) {
        // send login_success.html
        if (respBody.phone) {
          view.phone_num = respBody.phone.number;
        } else if (respBody.email) {
          view.email_addr = respBody.email.address;
        }
        var html = Mustache.to_html(loadLoginSuccess(), view);
        response.send(html);
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    // login failed
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end("Something went wrong here. :( ");
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Login_success.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AccountKitJS App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Logged In to Account Kit:</div>
  <div>User Token {{user_access_token}}</div>
  <div>User Token Expires at {{expires_at}}</div>
  <div>User Id {{user_id}}</div>
  <div>User phone: {{phone_num}}</div>
  <div>User email: {{email_addr}}</div>
</body>
```

I have started server.js (npm start). Running from direct url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the origin you are making the login call from is listed as an origin URL on your developer portal?

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the code, on the Facebook Developer page of your app, you have to add 'http://localhost:3000' in the Server URLs field and then save the changes by clicking the button in the right bottom. Now try signing in to the app again. Here is the [screenshot of the steps to fix the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOS3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In `AccountKit.init` you can set `debug: true`:

```
AccountKit.init({appId: 1, state: state, version: 'v1.0', debug: true})
```